# Does finish disposes all my activity elements?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm new in android development. I need to ask if it is 
essential to dispose all elements in my activity on destroy method, or if i will finish my activity it automatically dispose(destroy) all my activity elements.
My elements are Buttons,Listview,List,Animation Buttons,LinearLayouts.

```
 public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
}
```

Or if there is any other way which i can dispose(destroy) my elements in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. finish() will close the current activity and make the memory available for next garbage collection.

Comment: I know that closes my activity, but, is there any possibility to let an element, let's say a listview or animation unclose? The problem there is that the garbage collector will not free its memory till this item will close.

Comment: I didn't ask for activity, but for activity's elements

Comment: You can use weakreference for the items you wanted to clear

Comment: Can you give me an example or a link?